# QR/Barcode reader

Tags: android, qr, java

Здравствуйте. У меня стоит задача по инвентаризации товаров при помощи QR/Barcode reader'а. Поэтому возник вопрос, есть ли уже готовые библиотеки, которые помогут считать QR/Barcode? Или есть какие-то хитрости для обработки данных вещей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing).